# Convert ASP.NET textbox control .text contents to Date/Time format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, calendarextender, datetimeformatinfo

I am trying to insert into a database - various details about an event. The asp.net textbox is using the Calendar Extender (so a little calendar pops up and fills the textbox with a correctly formatted date). The EventDate field in my Access database is of the type Date/Time. I need to convert the text/string to date/time format

I have tried this so far:

VB:

> ```
> Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>
>     Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
>     Dim SqlString As String = "Insert into Events(EventTitle,EventDescription,EventDate,EventCategory) Values
>    (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4)"
>     Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
>
>     Dim strDate As String = tb_eventdate.Text
>     Dim dtfi As New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo
>     dtfi.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
>     dtfi.DateSeparator = "/"
>     Dim objDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate, dtfi)
>
>     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", tb_eventtitle.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", tb_eventdescription.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", tb_eventdate.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", dd_eventcategory.Text)
>     oleDbConn.Open()
>     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep("2000")
>     Response.Redirect("~/calendar.aspx")
> End Sub
> ```

Here is my clientside code just for reference:

> ```
>  <h1>Add An Event!<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager
>  ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" 
>                    runat="server">
>                </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
>             </h1>
>             <p>Title of Event:
>                 <asp:TextBox ID="tb_eventtitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
>             </p>
>             <p>Event Description:
>                 <asp:TextBox ID="tb_eventdescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
>             </p>
>             <p>Event Date:
>                 <asp:TextBox ID="tb_eventdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
>                 <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="tb_eventdate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
>                     TargetControlID="tb_eventdate">
>                 </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
>             </p>
>             <p>Event Category:
>                 <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_eventcategory" runat="server" 
>                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryTitle" 
>                     DataValueField="CategoryTitle">
>                 </asp:DropDownList>
>             </p>
>             <p>
>                 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
>             </p>
> ```

When I try to fill out the form, I receive this error:

[image: date time error]

My Two questions are:

1. What is wrong with the code above, and how do I successfully use the DateTimeFormatInfo class to convert String to Date/Time?
2. On a side note, the Calendar Extender inputs the date into the textbox in American Time format (MM/DD/YYYY), how do I change this to British (DD/MM/YYYY) format (I couldn't see an obvious property in the properties dialog to do this?)

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Adam

EDIT: Updated code below:

> ```
> Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>
>     Dim oleDbConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
>     Dim SqlString As String = "Insert into Events(EventTitle,EventDescription,EventDate,EventCategory) Values
>  (@f1,@f2,@f3,@f4)"
>     Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, oleDbConn)
>     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", tb_eventtitle.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f2", tb_eventdescription.Text)
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f3", DateTime.ParseExact(tb_eventdate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
>    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
>     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f4", dd_eventcategory.Text)
>     oleDbConn.Open()
>     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
>     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep("2000")
>     Response.Redirect("~/calendar.aspx")
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend you use `DateTime.ParseExact` static method, especially this oveload:

`DateTime.ParseExact(textBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",`**`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`**`)`

This will parse the text you have by the concrete format you specify (`"dd/MM/yyyy"` currently, **case is important** since `mm` is minutes as opposed to `MM` being months). Use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` guarantees that date separators will be retrieved from the format string (the second parameter). I have noticed that if current culture is used, it overrides some aspects of the format string you pass to `ParseExact`.

---

#### A note on CultureInfo

Invariant culture is good also for the reason that your local dev environment may have different regional information setup than the deployment environment. Usually, .NET uses the **current culture** in all `.ToString` calls and implicit formatting or parsing. When forcing a format and culture invariance explicitly, you are less prone to problems you cannot reproduce locally but exist on the production application.

---

#### A note on date/time formats

With exact parsing, the datetime format is expected to *strictly* match the format of the input. You should then take into consideration the following examples:

- `dd` matches two-digit days only. So `"dd/MM/yyyy"` it will match `"01/01/2013"`, but will fail for `"1/1/2013"` because it expects the exact number of digits for the day part. If you do not want leading zeros use: `d/M/yyyy` instead. Single letter means one digit for days less than `10` and two digits for the others.
- `MM` matches two-digit month, so all that applies to `dd` vs. `d` is the same for months.
- `yyyy` expects the year to be in 4 digits. If you use two-digit year, use `yy` instead.

---

#### A note on some ADO.NET providers

As it turns out to be the case with MS Access, the correctly parsed date-time object is not sufficient to make the query work. Currently, the following code

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(...)
```

is used to add parameters to the query. However, this approach omits passing information to the ADO.NET db provider that tells what database type to use for the parameter. I have read on some forums that MS Access/OleDb is not capable to resolve the correct type in all cases. Therefore I recommend the following approach:

```
Dim prm as OleDbParameter = _
   New OleDbParameter("@dateTimeParameterName", OleDbType.DateTime)
prm.Value = value  'value is an instance of `System.DateTime` parsed 
                   'from the input
cmd.Parameters.Add(prm)
```

The above code allows to specify the parameter database type explicitly, so the OleDb driver is now capable of correctly passing the `DateTime` object to the MS Access database.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have updated my code to reflect your advice. However I am still getting the "not recognized as valid datetime" error. Could you post some working code so that I can understand the syntax / format of DateTime.ParseExact method?

Comment: @adaam, I revisited my answer to address some additional formatting issues you may have experienced. Still I am not exactly sure what is wrong with your code. Can you tell me when do you receive the error? Does the call to `DateTime.ParseExact` fail, or it fails after it reaches the database? If the latter, maybe the parameter is not accepted correctly by the database.

Comment: The call succeeds - the value from the textbox is passed (see this screenshot of my debugging process: http://www.wherelionsroam.co.uk/valuepassed.PNG). The "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error is thrown when it reaches cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: (P.s the screenshot above i have used Parse, but I have also followed your advice and used ParseExact but still receive errors)

Comment: @adaam, it looks the problem comes from db type mismatching. What datatype is your column? Maybe specifying the parameter type by using `OleDbType.DateTime`/`OleDbType.SmallDateTime` when passing the parameter to the query will work? At least, it is there I believe the problem occurs, as parsing would have already suceeded. Try to debug and see what `DateTime` object is actually passed - move it into local var instead of having the `ParseExact` call where you add the parameter.

Comment: Data type in Access is "Date/Time" for the EventDate column. How would I specify the Parameter Type using OleDbType.Datetime?

Comment: Use `OleDbParameter prm = new OleDbParameter(parameterName, parameterType);` to create a parameter object; Use `prm.Value = value;` where `value` is the parsed date object, and then use `cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);`

Comment: Thank you I finally got it working. I used your method above (defining the parameter type seemed to do the trick!)

Answer (score 0):

**I used below short code:**

```
//myDateValue is System.DateTime object.
OleDbCommand commandObject = new OleDbCommand(); 
...   
commandObject.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ADDED_DATE_PARAM", OleDbType.Date).Value = myDateValue);
```