# How to store date from text box in SQL Server through C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am having trouble while storing date in sql server DB through C# asp.net, online

I have used asp Text box and asp calender extender in ASP file to get date from user,

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_date"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="cal_date" TargetControlID="txt_date"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

code behind file is, assume connection and command are declared and initialized ,

```
mycom = new SqlCommand("insert into mytable(dtCol1) values('"+Convert.ToDateTime(txt_dob.Text).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + "')", mycon);mycom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Problem is, when I select date less than 12 of any month it works perfect,
but when date/day is  greater than 12 of any month it gives error,

```
Exception Details: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

I have tried all combinations of .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

Please Help 
thanks in advance

Comment: what format are you using in writting datetime value in `txt_dob`

Comment: If you have problem for days over 12th it means you have wrong date format and storing month as a day and the other way around. Check what exactly format you have to send to SQL. Preferably use parameters not glued quries - it's bad habit you risk SQL injection.

Comment: thanks @Rajeev Kumar - it is taking default time format of calender extender which is , mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: I can't believe anyone hasn't picked up on the fact that he/she is writing Sql on the fly using a friggin (laser) SqlCommand!! <-- Which is BAD(tm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles style = DateTimeStyles.None;
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(txt_dob.Text, "m-d-yyyy", provider, style, out dt);
mycom = new SqlCommand("insert into mytable(dtCol1) values(@datevalue)", mycon);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@datevalue",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value =dt;
mycom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: hey thanks Rajeev , can u tell me what is 'strDate' and 'format' in DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate, format, provider, style, out dt);

Comment: Check if `dt` got correct datetime value on debug before insert it into sql

Comment: Did you get any issue here.

Comment: -1 For not using parametised sql. This approach is wide open for sql injection attacks

Comment: @JonP I have updated my answer to parametrized Query. Now hope it make sense for you :)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
mycom = new SqlCommand("insert into mytable(dtCol1) values(@value1)");
mycom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1",Convert.ToDateTime(txt_dob.Text));
mycom.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This answer works better than the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to come from here: `Convert.ToDateTime(txt_dob.Text)`. This type of conversion is not good because:

- **It disregards the format that the control uses**. `Convert.ToDateTime(...)` expects the string to be in a certain format(s) in order to parse it correctly. This cannot handle any custom formats that the `txt_dob` could use.
- **It is ignorant of culture-specific formatting.** Internally, `Convert.ToDateTime(...)` will probably stick to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, which is not said to be capable of parsing the date. Also, some front-end controls in .NET recognize and use the client culture passed by the browser (for web apps), and it is likely for that culture to be different than the server culture. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` will represent the server-side culture and formatting discrepancies are possible to occur

If you know the format of the `txt_dob.Text` you have to explicitly parse it. In the example below I have assumed the format is `"MM/dd/yyyy"`:

```
String dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";//The format that the txt_dob control uses
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    txt_dob.Text, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also check [this related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853054/convert-asp-net-textbox-control-text-contents-to-date-time-format/15853109#15853109) with some additional information on a similar case like yours

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR; You're using the wrong DateTime *format*.

There's plenty of issues here that will blow up Death Stars, left right and center.

Firstly, you're creating the sql query on the fly - that's probably the biggest no-no in the last 10 years and everyone has stopped doing that. In other words, please please please don't start doing (the very out of date) ADO.NET programming to pass data from the website to the database. Modern replacements like Entity Framework, NHibernate or even Linq2Sql if you're desperate.

Ok - that said, lets try and answer your question none-the-less.

The reason is because u're passing in the values in the wrong format. You're doing dates first. Your sql server is probably wanting it to be MONTHS first. Because it's probably been setup to be *style 121* (<-- that's a real technical sql server setting thing for Compatibility crap..)

But don't try and fight and guess.

Lets use a more universal and start string format: **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms**

eg.

```
SELECT CAST('2013-02-08 09:53:56.223' as DateTime)
```

And you can [see this in action over at SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/12255).

[This is a really good StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769547/sql-server-datetime-format) that explains what the default DateTime format is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
mycom = new SqlCommand("insert into mytable (dtCol1) values ('" +  Convert.ToDateTime(txt).ToString("MMM-dd-yyyy") + "')", mycon);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

User DateTime.ParseExact() in place of Convert.ToDateTime() method.

```
dateString = "12-31-2012";
format = "MM-dd-yyyy";
try 
{
  DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
catch (FormatException) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[Date_Of_Birth]='" + Convert.ToDateTime(TxtDate_Of_Birth.Text).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "'`

Will help the cause of error that sqlserver accepts datetime in format `MM/dd/yyyy`, but not in `dd/MM/yyyy`.